# How to make emacs accept UTF-8 from the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, emacs, utf-8, emacsw32

My friends have persuaded me to "try again" (about the 5th time in about 12 years) with emacs. I'm currently suffering a little, and need help with emacs + utf-8.

I'm running the 23.3.1 emacs gui on Windows 7 with my own custom keyboard layout (built with MS Keyboard Layout Creator). The layout has a full ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) character set, plus some additional characters from ISO-8859-9 (Latin-5, ğış etc for Turkish) and ŵ for Welsh (don't know where that one lives).

In my .emacs, I have (blindly) added these lines:

(Update: here's the latest evolving mess:)

```
;; set up unicode
;; keyboard / input method settings
(setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-language-environment 'UTF-8) ; prefer utf-8 for language settings
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(setq default-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))
(prefer-coding-system       'utf-8)
(setq buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(setq default-file-name-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(setq default-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(setq default-process-coding-system '(utf-8-unix . utf-8-unix))
(setq default-sendmail-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(setq default-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
```

Now, when I enter characters from ISO Latin-1 from the keyboard, they are accepted without problems, but characters from outside Latin-1 are "translated" to an approximate character *in* Latin-1. Thus, for example, Latin-5 "ğ" gets converted to a plain "g".

Cutting and pasting, however, work fine.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I should like to make *everything* I do with emacs utf-8 with BOM.

Comment: Is this in Emacs GUI, or the console version?

Comment: @grawity: The GUI. I've updated the question.

Comment: [Welsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_language) is spoken in and around Wales :)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Yes, I live there; I don't know on which ISO-8859 subpage, if any, the ŵs live...

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159693/how-can-i-make-sure-emacs-always-saves-edited-created-plain-text-as-utf8 help?

Comment: @N.N. Hi! Fancy meeting you here! No, I'm afraid it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it was a problem of codepage (and hence specific to Windows) because Emacs internally used old Windows APIs that could only return chars that belong to your codepage (hence Windows turned `ğ` into a plain `g` before passing it to Emacs).

AFAIK this is not the case any more in newer Emacsen (we now use the newer APIs which use some kind of Unicode, probably UTF-16).

Comment: Thank you; I can confirm that my current emacs doesn't suffer from this affliction!

Answer (score 0):

My emacs says that set-language-environment takes a string, not a symbol.

```
(set-language-environment "UTF-8")
```

Does using utf-16 for the keyboard encoding system work?

Comment: Sorry, `set-language-environment "UTF-8"` has no effect, while `(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-16)` gives "error: Unsuitable coding system for keyboard: utf-16"

Comment: I would guess that you would need to patch emacs to get it working then. There is a windows message called WM_UNICHAR that might help.

Answer (score 0):

on my linux box, I can type greek, french (accents) and spanish (ñ) on emacs with just these lines in my .emacs:

```
;; Set encoding
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8)
```

Comment: Just tried it. Thank you for trying, but it still doesn't accept non-ISO-8859-1 characters like ŵ and ş.

Comment: That is strange, I mean greek is certainly not in ISO-8859-1 right? Are you sure you are using a font that supports these characters?

Comment: Oh, yes. Cut-and-paste works fine; it's just the direct entry from the keyboard that doesn't work correctly. How do you enter your Greek characters?

Answer (score 0):

I added at the begining of my `init.el`:

```
(require 'iso-transl)
```

And it accepts my spanish inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, my spanish inputs are already working OK (as is all of ISO-9959-1). When I switch to Turkish (ı, İ, ş, Ş, ğ, Ğ) that emacs misbehaves, with or without iso-transl